# display page from other war

Tags: jsf

Is it possible to display a JSF page from another deployed war inside a page?

My case:
I've got war1.war with the page includeMeInWar2.xhtml.
And war2.war which should include the xhtml from war1. Note that there are some backingbean methods declared in the xhtml which have to be invoked in war1.war, but the content has to be displayed in war2.war.

JSF 2.1

Comment: @BalusC It's not really a modular JSF project. It's to tweak something with camunda (a BMPN process engine)..

Comment: So when I would include an iframe, the content is displayed in war2 and the methods behind it are invoked in war1?